create executable jar of karate testSuite , features are present src/test/java (maven project )
I want to create an executable jar of my karate test suite created with maven.so that I can run the testcases directly using the jar .The testcases are present in src/test/java and some required resource are present in src/main/java and src/test/java both .
Thanking you in advance...
